# Instantiation error

Tags: java

I am following a beginner's java book and one of the projects is to pick an error from commonly thrown errors and try to do what you can to induce the error.

I picked InstantiationError and am up to the level of knowing you can't instantiate abstract classes or interfaces. The docs says the error is usually caught by the compiler but can be thrown at runtime if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.

I don't know how a class definition could be changed while the program is running and am looking for some tips on where I should read further. 
Thanks!

Comment: What book are you reading? That seems like an unusual approach, but it's a good way to learn about errors.

Comment: It's actually the Java SE 7 Study Guide by Robert Liguori, I have a few books going at the same time and mixed them up slightly. The chapter is about exception handling and lists errors in java.lang for readers to choose one from.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I don't know how a class definition could be changed while the program is running

It can't change *while it's running* but it can change *after you've compiled*.

For example, try this:

```
// In Test.java
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(new Foo());
    }
}

// In Foo.java
public class Foo {
}
```

Compile:

```
javac Foo.java Test.java
```

Run:

```
java Test

// Some output like this...
Foo@1d6535bf
```

Now change `Foo.java` like this:

```
// No parameterless constructor any more!
public class Foo {
    public Foo(int x) {
    }
}
```

Recompile *just* `Foo.java`:

```
javac Foo.java
```

And rerun Test:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Foo: method <init>()V 
    not found
    at Test.main(Test.java:3)
```

This is *not* what I'd call a "commonly thrown error" though.

Note that that's not `InstantiationError` - but you can change `Foo.java` again, to:

```
public interface Foo {
}
```

Again, just recompile `Foo.java` and this time you'll get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InstantiationError: Foo
        at Test.main(Test.java:3)
```

Comment: I guess this kind of errors appear when manually compiling your classes or when updating a jar that strangely changes a class for an abstract class or interface without notice.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Indeed. I can't remember the last time it happened to me. *Very* rare.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! The book lists it as a common error in java.lang but it looks like maybe it doesn't happen very often at all.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe when you instantiate an abstract class at runtime using reflection.

Code sample:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass{
}

public class MyMainClass() {
    public void test(String[] args) {
             this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("MyAbstractClass").getConstructors()[0].newInstance();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1: It would be great if you post a code sample :) (note that OP's reading a beginner's Java book).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html), which offers a way to instantiate a class by name.

```
public void throwError() {
    AbstractType type = this.getClassLoader().newInstance("my.abstract.Type");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple thing that can cause this type of error is if you try to create an object with the wrong number of parameters. say the constructor takes two parameters, but you have your interface designed in such a way that the user could input 3 or more parameters. normally, the number of parameters would be caught by the compiler, but if it was created "on the fly" then it would get caught at runtime